# É errado deixar uma FK dentro da Própria tabela que origina a PK?

Tags: sql

É errado fazer isso em uma tabela de banco?

Vou citar um exemplo:

Temos o Cliente: Google
E nele temos a unidade: Google Brasil

Então temos a seguinte exemplo de tabela:
Tabela Cliente

```
Id | Nome          | Matriz 
1  | Google        | null

Id | Nome          | Matriz
2  | Google Brasil |  1
```

Ou seja, deixei, meu Cliente e Unidade tudo na mesma tabela, deixando apenas uma coluna Matriz para diferenciar se é ou não uma Unidade de alguma matriz

É errado fazer isso? É bom? quais prós e contra em fazer essa estrutura?

Comment: Depende do objetivo dessa tabela. Se você tem uma hierarquia simples, essa abordagem facilitará na construção de selects sem joins, porém você fica amarrado nessa hierarquia simples (Não permite relação n-n)

Comment: Não consegui imaginar aonde não me deixaria ter N-N

Comment: n-n - muitos pra muitos. Google Brasil não poderia estar um nível abaixo de Google USA e Google Singapura ao mesmo tempo nessa modelagem. (Assumi somente como exemplo.)

Comment: Difícil que uma unidade de empresa ter mais de uma matriz, já diz né, matriz, única, rsrsrs, atualmente eu deixo em tabela separada, mas pensei nisso que pode me dar um aumento de performance, e também, uma facilidade, já que no código, eu deixo como composição apenas o "Cliente", e nele já sei se os dados vai para a matriz ou unidade

Comment: @Caffé o que quis dizer sem os joins foi que para buscar todas as filias da companhia X, basta um `WHERE matriz = X`

Comment: Quanto ao aumento de performance, será que obtenho fazendo assim?

Comment: @Rod mas já escolheu a resposta correta ?

Comment: gmsantos, ambos ajudaram na resposta, apesar que as minhas maiores dúvidas estavam aqui nos comentários, se quiser elaborar uma resposta mais detalhada eu mudo conforme eu ache que é mais elaborada e mais detalhada para outros usuários veem

Comment: Embora seja um direito escolher uma resposta quando quiser, acho que você pode receber mais informação útil se deixar a questão aberta por um tempo. cc @gmsantos

Comment: Sim, você pode escolher a resposta no momento que entender Rod, porém isso pode desencorajar que incluam novas respostas.

Comment: Já editei, vou deixar aberta por enquanto

Comment: @Rod o nome até pode ser 'matriz' e ter uma significância maior no mundo real, mas em domínio de dados matriz seria apenas uma companhia sem... matriz. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, não é errado.

Se Google e Google Brasil são o mesmo tipo de entidade (ambos são clientes), é natural que sejam persistidos na mesma tabela.

Se um cliente pode ter uma matriz ou filiais, e a matriz e cada filial são um cliente distinto, é natural que fiquem todos na tabela cliente.

Se você pretende relacionar um cliente filial com o cliente matriz desta filial, é natural esta chave estrangeira apontando para a mesma tabela.

Considerando apenas o que você expôs, não há pontos negativos na modelagem desta tabela.

### Consideremos agora outro cenário:

Google e Google Brasil não são ambos clientes. Apenas Google, a matriz, é cliente (por exemplo, você só fatura contra o Google Matriz). Google Brasil é uma filial que você precisa conhecer por alguma demanda de negócio, mas não é seu cliente. Neste caso, é errado deixar matriz e filial na mesma tabela?

**Resposta:** Ainda assim não é errado que estejam na mesma tabela se a tabela armazena basicamente os mesmos atributos (CNPJ, Endereço, Telefone...).

Mas neste caso você teria que mudar o nome da tabela pois uma tabela chamada "Clientes" só deveria armazenar clientes. Você poderia chamá-la por exemplo de "Pessoas" ou "PessoasJurídicas" ou "Parceiros" ou o que fizesse mais sentido para o seu domínio.

No momento que esta tabela tivesse vários campos exclusivos para o cliente em si ou vários campos exclusivos para as unidades, você deveria refatorar em mais de uma tabela.

Quanto a performance, você precisa partir de um problema conhecido, ou mesmo especulado mas que possa ser elaborado como um problema bem definido. Então você faz alguns estudos para comprovar e resolver este problema. Não assuma problemas de performance não óbvios que você não possa comprovar por sua experiência ou por testes.

### Concluindo:

- Nomeie a tabela de modo coerente com os seus registros.
- Não há problema em manter em uma mesma tabela entidades de tipos diferentes no domínio se elas tiverem os mesmos atributos e desde que haja, por assim dizer, um tipo comum na hierarquia acima dessas tabelas. Estou falando conceitualmente, exemplo: "Matriz" e "Unidades" são entidades diferentes no domínio, mas é possível um entendimento de uma entidade comum - ambas são "Pessoas Jurídicas" com as quais você tem contato.

A seguir são sugestões e alguém pode encontrar bons motivos em contrário, embora eu próprio não os visualize:

- Armazene em tabelas distintas entidades que não possuem nada em comum além dos nomes de alguns atributos.
- Armazene em tabelas distintas entidades que possuem algo em comum mas que possuem mais diferenças que semelhanças.
- Busque desenvolver o software de modo que ele sofra um impacto reduzido quando da refatoração do banco de dados - assim você pode evoluir o design do banco ao longo do ciclo de vida do sistema.

O ponto negativo de não seguir estas sugestões é você acabar gerando uma tabela com muitas colunas onde muitas delas não fazem sentido para todos os registros. Nesta situação, o entendimento da tabela é prejudicado e começam a surgir campos redundantes ou campos com mais de um objetivo, prejudicando ainda mais o entendimento, te jogando em um ciclo vicioso de aumento de complexidade.

Comment: Caffé, pode me exemplificar algum ponto negativo que eu possa ter?

Comment: @Rod Elaborei mais a minha resposta de modo a encontrar pontos negativos.

Comment: @Caffé Excelentes pontos, +1. Comentário: '[...]acabar gerando uma tabela com muitas colunas onde muitas delas não fazem sentido para todos os registros[...]' - Vale mencionar que isso tem a ver com Densidade de Dados. Tabelas com muitos campos em branco = baixa densidade = desperdício de processamento em lookups. http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/sparsity-and-density

Comment: Caffé, gostei da sua resposta, obrigado por disponibilizar seu tempo para criar-la,agradecimentos ao gmsantos também que compartilhou ideias